# Accessibility with multiple <tbody> tags in a table

Tags: html, accessibility, nvda

I have multiple `<tbody>` sections in my `<table>` and it's reading each `<th>` tag the table contains. They have unique id and header attributes assigned to the various th and td tags so, to me, it doesn't make sense why the NVDA screen reader is outputting the following output:

```
[row# tbody 1, column header 1 name]
[<th> tbody 2, column header 1 name]
[<th> tbody 3, column header 1 name]
Current tbody 4, column header 1 name
[output of column1 data]
[output of column2 data]
[output of column3 data]
[output of column4 data]
```

The HTML is structured like this, [here is the Pen also showing this issue](http://codepen.io/benpetersen/pen/MyNMNj)

```css
caption{
  text-align:left;
  display: table-caption;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  width: 1px;
}
.left{
  text-align:left;
}
.right{
  text-align:right;
}
.hierarchy1{
  font-size:1.25em;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.hierarchy2{
  backgound-color:#ededed;
  padding: 9px 10px 7px 8px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.hierarchy3{
}
tr{
  height:45px;
  display:table-row;
}
table
{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption class="offScreen">Balance Sheet Table</caption>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="hierarchy0 bold">
    <th class="left" scope="col" id="date-cell-0-1">Assets (Millions)</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-1-1">9/30/2012</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-2-1">9/30/2013</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-3-1">9/30/2014</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-4-1">9/30/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy5">
    <td class="left" headers="date-cell-0-1">Cash</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-1">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-1">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-1">10,232.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-1">--</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy4">
    <td class="left" headers="date-cell-0-1">Cash Equivalents</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-1">10,746.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-1">14,259.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-1">13,844.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-1">21,120.00</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="hierarchy0 bold">
    <th class="left" scope="col" id="date-cell-0-2">Liability And Shareholder Equity (Millions)</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-1-2">9/30/2012</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-2-2">9/30/2013</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-3-2">9/30/2014</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-4-2">9/30/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy5">
    <td class="left" headers="date-cell-0-2">Accounts Payable</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-2">21,175.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-2">22,367.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-2">30,196.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-2">35,490.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy4">
    <td class="left" headers="date-cell-0-2">Income Tax Payable</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-2">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-2">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-2">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-2">--</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="hierarchy0 bold">
    <th class="left" scope="col" id="date-cell-0-3">Supplemental (Millions)</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-1-3">9/30/2012</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-2-3">9/30/2013</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-3-3">9/30/2014</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col" id="date-cell-4-3">9/30/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy1">
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-0-3">Total Capitalization</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-3">111,210.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-3">140,509.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-3">140,534.00</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-3">172,818.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy1">
    <td class="left" headers="date-cell-0-3">Capital Lease Obligations</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-3">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-3">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-3">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-3">--</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy1">
    <td class="left" headers="date-cell-0-3">Preferred Stock Equity</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-1-3">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-2-3">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-3-3">--</td>
    <td class="right" headers="date-cell-4-3">--</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

If you have any insight to this HTML structure and accessibility, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a typo: Your ids have "date**=**cell" for the first `th` tag, but when you set the headers attribute, you have "date**-**cell". Change the equals sign to a dash. (I was trying to bold where the error is, but it didn't work.)

Comment: Yep, that was a typo in the question. It's not related to the issue

Comment: Do you have a live example? It sounds like NVDA is doing what is supposed to do, but if your cells really contain the content I see above it can get pretty confusing. I have a [table in this CodePen](http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/ONaewv) you can try to see if it reads as you expect (note, no `<tbody>` as this was for a client demo). Also, note that the `id` attribute does nothing for NVDA here.

Comment: *It sounds like NVDA is doing what is supposed to do* @aardrian - Why is it supposed to read all the headers instead of just the one in the `headers` attribute? I would have expected the same as the OP and that it'd only read "[text from header] [text from cell]".

Comment: Again, it is possible I am confused given the text in your examples (I made a CodePen and pasted it in to test). Do you have a live example? Also, I wasn't clear in my comment. Maybe do not rely on `headers` attribute. Also, [look at this screen reader / browser support matrix](http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/tables/table-td-headers/) and see where you fall.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to a CodePen

Comment: You have duplicate IDs down the first column, so that is jacking up some announcements. Run this through a validator to find the dupes, and make sure the IDs are what you want. Make sure you use the arrow keys to go cell by cell so you can hear what each says. You are also seeing the topmost `<th>` get spoken always, no matter your headers attribute. You should consider dropping `headers=` unless you are overriding something.

Comment: I made a CodePen of this: http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/zBOYmN You also haven't said what browser/OS you are using with NVDA. Consider that NVDA plays best with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the comments, I found this issue is related to Chrome w/ NVDA. Firefox w/ NVDA works as expected.

To work cross browser w/ NVDA, I built multiple tables, one for each th, and removed the headers and id attributes because it makes more semantic sense to do so. Here's an [example of it working cross browser](http://codepen.io/benpetersen/pen/xOKgyd?editors=1100) (Chrome, Firefox) with NVDA

```
<table>
  <caption class="offScreen">Balance Sheet Table</caption>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="hierarchy0 bold">
    <th class="left" scope="col">Assets (Millions)</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2012</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2013</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2014</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy5">
    <td class="left">Cash</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">10,232.00</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy4">
    <td class="left">Cash Equivalents</td>
    <td class="right">10,746.00</td>
    <td class="right">14,259.00</td>
    <td class="right">13,844.00</td>
    <td class="right">21,120.00</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="hierarchy0 bold">
    <th class="left" scope="col">Liability And Shareholder Equity (Millions)</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2012</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2013</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2014</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy5">
    <td class="left">Accounts Payable</td>
    <td class="right">21,175.00</td>
    <td class="right">22,367.00</td>
    <td class="right">30,196.00</td>
    <td class="right">35,490.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy4">
    <td class="left">Income Tax Payable</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="hierarchy0 bold">
    <th class="left" scope="col">Supplemental (Millions)</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2012</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2013</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2014</th>
    <th class="right greyBL" scope="col">9/30/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy1">
    <td class="right">Total Capitalization</td>
    <td class="right">111,210.00</td>
    <td class="right">140,509.00</td>
    <td class="right">140,534.00</td>
    <td class="right">172,818.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy1">
    <td class="left">Capital Lease Obligations</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hierarchy1">
    <td class="left">Preferred Stock Equity</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
    <td class="right">--</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```